# Custom mongodb search object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm building my first node.js/angular app and cannot seem to find a solution for the following problem.

If I have a `User` Schema such as :

```
User = {
  firstname: "Bryan",
  lastname: "Allan",
  email: "noemail@example.com,
  skills: ["node.js", "angular", ..]
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to both:

**a.** Search on one or multiple fields?
**b.** Search for the instance of string?

For example, can I use a custom search object like:

```
search = {
  firstname: "Br",
  skills: "node.js"
}
```

and have it return the above document?  Is a search object the best solution?

Normally, I would return all `Users` and use an angular filter, but I'm worried that this approach won't scale nicely since there's going to be a large amount of users stored. With this in mind, I'd like to limit the results sent back to the browser if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an array just contains simple values (as in your example) you can just query it with

```
User.find({ firstname: "Br", skills: "node.js })
```

The mongoose method .find() is very powerfull.
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Or you could also use the aggregate() method
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize find would do a partial string match.